# vbs script access denied permission change

Tags: windows, vbscript

I want to change the permissions of etc/host file.

i am running this vbs script

```
Dim objShell
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
objShell.run "cmd cacls C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc /e /p everyone:f  "
Set objShell = Nothing
```

now the problem is that whenever i run this i get access denied. Yes, i am administrator.
but when i manually click the file and go to security settings and change permission, it prompt for domain admin name and password and when i enter it it works.

but with command line , how can i enable domain user name and password so that access is not denied. I want to integrate this in vbs script.

I hope i am clear and thank you

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have UAC enabled, so try running the command via [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537745%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the "runas" verb set:

```
cmd  = "cacls.exe"
args = "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc /e /p everyone:f"

Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
app.ShellExecute cmd, args, "", "runas", 0
```

However, I'd recommend using [`icacls`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx) rather than `cacls`. Also, granting everyone full control to the `etc` directory is a BAD IDEA. Don't actually do this.